# Automatically apply style files/symbology on a set of raster and vector layers QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, style-manager

The output of a model that works outside QGIS generates a set of outputs ranging from DEMs (tif), Slope, Silt content and many others. This output comes in the form of a zip.

This output data is shared to people who do not have real QGIS experience. What I would like to do is to provide them with the possibility to apply one styling ''package'' to all layers in an easy and convenient way.

I know that you can create and save style files for each layer and upload them. But I would like to know if there is a way to do this more efficiently.

**REMARK**  : the outputs from the model will always have the same name (DEM,SILT,BIOCLIMATE etc.) if that makes things easier

Comment: If you simply replace the old outputs with the new outputs using the same name wherever you store them, then when the projects are re-opened, they will be styled and defined in the same way.

Comment: Why not creating a QGIS project with all data styled ? (as your output have always the same name you could add to your model a step to copy a master QGIS project (with relative path) in the same folder as the .zip output)

Comment: Thank you @j.r. I think both of you explain the same solution. I tried the solution and it worked indeed. What I did now is apply styling to all layers manually once and then save the project. Then I deleted all the old files (because otherwise if I open the project file it will reopen the files from the initial path) and when I opened the project file it said that the layers were unavailable. With auto-find I could replace them with files from a different path that have the same name. Is this what you meant?

Comment: johns and I are suggesting almost same thing. johns assume that you overwrite the old data each time you run your model, if that's the case, opening the QGIS project will load the new data as they now replace the old. My solution apply if you want to keep previous data : your model output data in a different folder each time and you copy (either manually or as step in your model) the QGIS project in the same folder, if your QGIS project is set to relative path (and you originally created it in the same folder as the data) it will always load the data from the folder it is in.

Comment: @J.R thank you for synthesising and clearing up. All problems are now solved. So if I save the project file with a relative path and always send the .prj file inside the zip with the outputs it will automatically open the files and apply styles to the files in the folder its located in.